# Multiclassification Text LSTM Prediction

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nltk, multiclass-classification

I'm at a complete loss and at the stage where reading about this is confusing me all the more.
I have a data set of lyrics split into genres.
I got my data, extracted the lyrics (strings) and Genre (strings). I factorized the genre into 10 ints:

```
df['Genre'].factorize()
```

I cleaned and preprocessed the lyric strings, added the factorised genre data to the dataframe and then I split it into training and validation

```
lyrics_train,lyrics_test,gc_train,gc_test=train_test_split(lyrics,GC,test_size=0.2,random_state=123)
```

I then tokenized and sequenced the lyrics

```
vocab_size = 10000
embedding_dim = 50
max_length = 100
padding_type='post'
trunc_type='post'
oov_tok = "<OOV>"


tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = vocab_size, oov_token=oov_tok)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(lyrics_train)

word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print(len(word_index))
print(word_index)


lyrics_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(lyrics_train)
lyrics_train_final = pad_sequences(lyrics_train,maxlen=max_length, padding=padding_type, 
                       truncating=trunc_type)

lyrics_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(lyrics_test)
lyrics_test_final = pad_sequences(lyrics_test,maxlen=max_length, 
                               padding=padding_type, truncating=trunc_type)
```

Now I want to try and run the data through a most basic LSTM

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim,input_length=max_length))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

from what I undertand the final layer should be 10 due to there being 10 categories to predict on.
However I can only ever get the model to run (badly) against a single dense layer. Which isn't acting as a multi classification.
Can anyone point the error of my ways? I feel like I'm missing something in the process perhaps?

Comment: If you know that your last layer should have 10 neurons, why does the current one have just one?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy because when I try with a 10 neuron last layer I get the following error:
 ```ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 10) are incompatible```

Comment: Sure, that tells that your labels are not one-hot encoded, if you have integer labels, switch to sparse categorical cross-entropy. And please learn about XY problem, you  were asking about what you think the solution is, instead of asking about the actual problem.